# How do I rewrite my Rails validation rule so that it dosen't use underlying regular expressions?

Tags: ruby, regex, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 with PostGres 9.5.  I have this validation rule in my model

```
validates :name, presence: true
```

This invokes the underlying code in Rails (from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb) …

```
class String
  BLANK_RE = /\A[[:space:]]*\z/
…
  def blank?
    BLANK_RE === self
  end
```

When I set my model's name attribute to

```
"C\xE9dric Lanier”
```

and then call `#valid?` on my method, I get an encoding error:

> ((ArgumentError) invalid byte sequence in UTF-8)

How can I rewrite my validation rule, above, so that it doesn’t use underlying regular expressions?  Note this question is not about solving the encoding error.  I opened another question for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
validate :name_present

def name_present
  if name.mb_chars.tidy_bytes.to_s.blank?
    errors.add(:name, "can't be blank")
  end
end
```

It basically replaces weird characters:

```
"C\xE9dric Lanier".mb_chars.tidy_bytes.to_s # => "Cédric Lanier"
```